# CheckBoxPreference keeps checking itself, why?

Tags: android

I have a checkbox preference that is defined like this:

```
        <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="enable_sound"
        android:title="Play sounds"></CheckBoxPreference>
```

But despite the fact that this checkbox is unchecked, periodically I will start hearing my app play sounds, and when I got to my settings Activity I find the checkbox is checked again.   I am not setting the checkbox anywhere in my code, I am only reading it to determine whether to play certain sounds.  This is the only code referencing my "enable_sound" checkbox:

```
boolean do_sound = preferences.getBoolean("enable_sound",false);
if (do_sound) play_sound(sound_name);
```

I have not been able to deliberately get this to happen - for instance, if I dispose of the app in the app browser "screen" and start the app again, the preference is not checked.  It just seems to randomly happen after some period of time.

Why is this happening?  I'm not sure how to get to the bottom of this, because my usage seems pretty trivial with no obvious reason why it would happen.

Comment: Did you tried setting the *defaultValue* for your `CheckBoxPreference`: `android:defaultValue="false"` ?

Comment: @SudheeshR No.  I have 5 checkbox preferences, none have a default set in the XML. So I'm not sure why this would be the only one that spuriously gets checked.  But I can try it and see if it still keeps happening.